# Invert cmd.exe colors

Tags: colors, cmd.exe

cmd.exe is by default black background and white text. I want to invert this color scheme to be white background and black text.

I know you could do it in colors tab in properties, but sometimes it causes issues, especially with applications that internally change the text colors using ANSI color codes.

[image: issues]

Also it only changes the background from black to white and vice-versa for text, but I was hoping to invert the entire color spectrum because if an application decides to display yellow/green color, it just assumes that it'll be displayed on black background, and so when it's actually displayed on white background it is almost invisible (yellow-on-white).

What's the best way to invert the entire color scheme in cmd.exe console?

Answer (score 4):

The color table is stored in registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`

Save and execute this as `invert.reg`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"ColorTable00"=dword:00ffffff
"ColorTable01"=dword:007fffff
"ColorTable02"=dword:00ff7fff
"ColorTable03"=dword:007f7fff
"ColorTable04"=dword:00ffff7f
"ColorTable05"=dword:007fff7f
"ColorTable06"=dword:00ff7f7f
"ColorTable07"=dword:003f3f3f
"ColorTable08"=dword:007f7f7f
"ColorTable09"=dword:0000ffff
"ColorTable10"=dword:00ff00ff
"ColorTable11"=dword:000000ff
"ColorTable12"=dword:00ffff00
"ColorTable13"=dword:0000ff00
"ColorTable14"=dword:00ff0000
"ColorTable15"=dword:00000000
```

---

And following is the `default.reg` in case you want to go back

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"ColorTable00"=dword:00000000
"ColorTable01"=dword:00800000
"ColorTable02"=dword:00008000
"ColorTable03"=dword:00808000
"ColorTable04"=dword:00000080
"ColorTable05"=dword:00800080
"ColorTable06"=dword:00008080
"ColorTable07"=dword:00c0c0c0
"ColorTable08"=dword:00808080
"ColorTable09"=dword:00ff0000
"ColorTable10"=dword:0000ff00
"ColorTable11"=dword:00ffff00
"ColorTable12"=dword:000000ff
"ColorTable13"=dword:00ff00ff
"ColorTable14"=dword:0000ffff
"ColorTable15"=dword:00ffffff
```